# Wall post permission not showing

Tags: c#, vk

I am using http as redirect url.
This is my request url:
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?response_type=code&scope=wall,photos,offline&client_id=xxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://octadd.gi0.io/vkoauth/RecieveCode

`wall` permission is not showing in confirmation window. What to do for that to show?

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://vk.com/dev.php?method=openapi#/dev/permissions), `wall` access permission provides

> Access to standard and advanced methods for the wall. **Note that this access permission is unavailable for sites (it is ignored at attempt of authorization)**

By the given URL, I can suppose that you are a web-site, and that's the reason.

Comment: suppose if i'm test on localhost,then?

Comment: @SagarVardani There is no way to get this access, if you are developing a web-site authorization. You need to either implement a client application (and choose this in aplication settings) or stop using `wall` methods.

Comment: I want to post on wall using access_token so wall permission is required for that. I tried both Standalone Application and website. Every time got error code 15 access denied.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `redirect_uri` to `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html` it will prompt you for wall permission.

See https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user